# Maven verify build failure but 0 failures

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

So I run locally `mvn verify -Pintegration-tests -Pcode-coverage spotbugs:spotbugs` and got:

Results:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 342, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report (post-integration-test) @ x---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/xTeam/x/merge-request/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'x' with 129 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:3.0.1:validateRevision (validate-the-git-infos) @ x---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:verify (default) @ x---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-12T09:38:14+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [jenkins-event-spy] Generated /var/jenkins_home/workspace/x Team/x/merge-request@tmp/withMavenc11f7343/maven-spy-20191212-093205-93012816127390747730671.log
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:verify (default) on project x: There are test failures.
```

Pretty strange to me cause of there are no Failures (0). I run out of ideas. Can anyone help me guess why is it failing despite 0 failures?

Maven failsafe:

```
 <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>integration-tests</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Try building with `-X` parameter and see if you can find any error in the verbose logs.

Comment: First upgrade to most recent version 3.0.0-M4 ...

Comment: Sadly -X did not provide any additional informations nor upgrading to M4 ; (